# Split a column data using another column data in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column A which is the subset of another column B in my dataframe. I want to split the data in the parent column B with A so I get the remaining of B in a new column C. I was trying the below piece using lambda. But the inner column is A which I mention as Series can't be converted into str.

```
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.split(df['A'],1)[1])
```

Example DF:

```
B                       A
Ford F-Series pickup    Ford
Toyota Camry            Toyoto
Ford Taurus/Taurus X    Ford
```

Needed Output Data column:

```
C
F-Series pickup
Camry
Taurus/Taurus X
```

Here as the df['A'] is a series, we need it as a data from each row to do the same. Is there any possibility to pass the column A data as string. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add an example of df and your desired output.

Comment: @Craig Apologies. Added example for problem definition.

Comment: No worries, the example made it clear what you were trying to do. I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you aren't just trying to remove the model name, but also remove everything before the name.

The code below accomplishes what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'A':['Ford', 'Toyota', 'Ford'], 
                    'B':['Ford F-Series pickup', 'Toyota Camry', 'Ford Taurus/Taurus X']} )

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'].split(x['A'], 1), axis=1)['B']
print(df)
```

Produces:

```
        A                     B                 C
0    Ford  Ford F-Series pickup   F-Series pickup
1  Toyota          Toyota Camry             Camry
2    Ford  Ford Taurus/Taurus X   Taurus/Taurus X
```

Comment: Thanks @Craig. Your solution is accurate. Worked. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.replace` method. Since you will create a leading whitespace after replacing the brand name with nothing, the `.strip` method will remove those.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["Ford", "Audi"], 'B': ["Ford Pickup", "Audi R8"]})

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'].replace(x['A'], '').strip(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way of doing this is by creating a list that loops through the `.values` of the columns you're seeking to perform string operations on.

In your example it would look like this:

`df['C'] = [b.split(a)[0] for (b, a) in df[['B', 'A']].values]`

To show that this is more efficient I ran the following test using one of my own datasets from google analytics:

**Vector Solution**

CPU times: user 30.8 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 30.8 ms
Wall time: 32.7 ms

`appended_ga4_data['top_level'] = [y.split(x)[0] for (y, x) in appended_ga4_data[['Page path and screen class', 'subject']].values]`

If we wanted to use the vector solution to get the second (or nth) element in the split, then we would need to include a conditional check that the list is long enough to get the index (assuming the split doesn't always apply):

**Vector Solution with Conditions**

CPU times: user 53.9 ms, sys: 635 µs, total: 54.5 ms
Wall time: 66.4 ms

`appended_ga4_data['top_level'] = [y.split(x)[1] if len(y.split(x))>1 else y.split(x)[0] for (y, x) in appended_ga4_data[['Page path and screen class', 'subject']].values]`

**Apply Solution**

CPU times: user 245 ms, sys: 6.59 ms, total: 251 ms
Wall time: 263 ms

`appended_ga4_data['top_level'] = appended_ga4_data.apply(lambda x: x['Page path and screen class'].split(x['subject'])[0], axis=1)`